# Is it possible to use both space and enter for taking input in c++?

Tags: c++, input, io, inputstream

I want to make a program that takes a list of numbers and reads the input.
The problem is that the input will be taken with both spaces and enters. The values are integers.

An example of the list:

```
3
2 1 2
2 2 1
5 5 4 3 2 1
```

Please don't be too hard on me, as I am just learning C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int var;
    cin >> var; cin.get();

    cout << var;
    return 0;
}
```

So, when pressing either <kbd>Space</kbd> or <kbd>Enter</kbd>, I want it to take the value of `var`, instead of only pressing <kbd>Space</kbd>.

Comment: "i wanted it to take a instead" - Take a what?

Comment: User input is one of the less delightful part of coding. The code you are sharing does not appear to be doing what you think.

Comment: Unless configured otherwise, the terminal will only send complete lines to your program when the `Enter` key is pressed.

Comment: You probably want to use std::getline() to read your lines of varying number of ints into a std::string. And use istringstream to read them out into ints.

Answer (score 3):

In your example input, the first number appears to be the number of rows present, and the first number of each row appears to be the number of values present in that row.

If so, then simply write your code logic accordingly, eg:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    unsigned int numRows, numValues, var;

    cin >> numRows;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < numRows; ++i)
    {
        cin >> numValues;
        for(unsigned int j = 0; j < numValues; ++j)
        {
            cin >> var;
            ...
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`operator>>` treats both <kbd>Space</kbd> and <kbd>Enter</kbd> as whitespace, so you don't need to differentiate between them in this situation.